# How to change a message in AlertDialog, everytime I click a different image in andriod?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am beginner to android. I want to display a image description(Using AlertDialog) when a user click the image. But the AlertDialog box always shows the first saved message when I click the other image also? It doesn't reset when I click other images. Anyone please help me?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    ImageView imageView,imgpt1,imgpt2,imgpt3,imgpt4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewspinner);
        imgpt1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagepart1);
        imgpt2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagepart2);
        imgpt3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagepart3);
        imgpt4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagepart4);

        imgpt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgpt2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgpt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgpt4.setOnClickListener(this);
        List<String> categories=new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Front View");
        categories.add("Side View");
        categories.add("Back View");
        categories.add("Top View");

        ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,categories);
        stringArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carfrontview);
                    imgpt1.setImageResource(R.drawable.frontbumpers);
                    imgpt1.setTag("frontbumpers");
                    imgpt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.frontfenders);
                    imgpt2.setTag("frontfenders");
                    imgpt3.setImageResource(R.drawable.frontgrilles);
                    imgpt2.setTag("frontgrilles");
                    imgpt4.setImageResource(R.drawable.frontheadlight);
                    imgpt2.setTag("frontheadlight");
                }
                else if(position==1)
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carsideview);
                    imgpt1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidebumpers);
                    imgpt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidedoor);
                    imgpt3.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidefuelcovers);
                    imgpt4.setImageResource(R.drawable.sidemirror);

                }
                else if(position==2)
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbackview);
                    imgpt1.setImageResource(R.drawable.backrearbumpers);
                    imgpt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.backrearmirror);
                    imgpt3.setImageResource(R.drawable.backrearwindow);
                    imgpt4.setImageResource(R.drawable.backtaillights);
                }
                else if(position==3)
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cartopview);
                    imgpt1.setImageResource(R.drawable.topbattery);
                    imgpt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.topfuelinjection);
                    imgpt3.setImageResource(R.drawable.topoildipstick);
                    imgpt4.setImageResource(R.drawable.topradiator);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String message="";
        if(imgpt1.getTag()=="frontbumpers")
        {
            message="This is Bumper";
        }
        else if(imgpt1.getTag()=="frontfenders")
        {
            message="This is Fenders";
        }
        else if(imgpt1.getTag()=="frontheadlight")
        {
            message="This is headlight";
        }
        else if(imgpt1.getTag()=="frontgrilles")
        {
            message="This is grilles";
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Car Parts");
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();

    }
}
```

Comment: please avoid these answers with `equal` suggestion. everyone has a misleading answer. you have a problem with the `view` which you are checking. i posted an answer go through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are using **imgpt1** in every case which should not be the scenario.
Rather use

```
v.getTag.equals("xxx")
```

After resolving that try to use the best android practice for comparison of strings.

Best practice while checking the strings in android(Java) first check the null and empty string using

```
String string1 = "abc", string2 = "Abc";
TextUtils.isEmpty(string1); // Returns true if the string is empty or null
```

Then check for the equal cases by using the below mentioned code

```
string1.equals(string2) //Checks with case sensitivity
string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2) // Checks without case sensitivity. Here this will return true.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

If You have to check Strings use **.equals()** ,in case of int use **==**

```
if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontbumpers"))
{
     message="This is Bumper";
}
else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontfenders"))
{
     message="This is Fenders";
}
else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontheadlight"))
{
     message="This is headlight";
}
else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontgrilles")
{
     message="This is grilles";
}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve his problem :) it's just suggestion to use equals ! misleading answer

Answer (score 2):

In `onClick` use

`imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontgrilles")`

**instead of**

```
imgpt1.getTag()=="frontgrilles"
```

Comment: this doesn't solve his problem :) it's just suggestion to use `equals` ! misleading answer

Answer (score 1):

You should check the tag of the `view` not the static item as they will be always true!  look at your first condition. `imgpt1` tag is "`frontbumpers`" thus that condition is always true! hence it shows the same message every time.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String message="";

//for your clarification here v is the view which was clicked ex. impt1 or 2 3 4.... or anything which has an onClick listener assigned and was click will call this method. 

        if(v.getTag()=="frontbumpers")
        {
            message="This is Bumper";
        }
        else if(v.getTag()=="frontfenders")
        {
            message="This is Fenders";
        }
        else if(v.getTag()=="frontheadlight")
        {
            message="This is headlight";
        }
        else if(v.getTag()=="frontgrilles")
        {
            message="This is grilles";
        }
}
```

> ** recommended to use `equals()` rather than `==` for `String`. change to `v.getTag().equals("someValueYouWantToCheck")

Answer (score 1):

In onClick method, you used first image for all if else conditions, that is why, no matter which image you click, it'll show first image message.

```
    String message="";
    if(**imgpt1.getTag()**=="frontbumpers")
    {
        message="This is Bumper";
    }
    else if(**imgpt1.getTag()**=="frontfenders")
    {
        message="This is Fenders";
    }
    else if(**imgpt1.getTag()**=="frontheadlight")
    {
        message="This is headlight";
    }
    else if(**imgpt1.getTag()**=="frontgrilles")
    {
        message="This is grilles";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. Just now I saw it. I changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `imgpt1.getTag().equals("string")` instead of `imgpt1.getTag()=="string"`

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String message="";
    if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontbumpers"))
    {
        message="This is Bumper";
    }
    else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontfenders"))
    {
        message="This is Fenders";
    }
    else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontheadlight"))
    {
        message="This is headlight";
    }
    else if(imgpt1.getTag().equals("frontgrilles"))
    {
        message="This is grilles";
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Car Parts");
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).create().show();

}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve his problem :) it's just suggestion to use equals ! misleading answer